# Problems with adding an extension in Magento Root directory?

Tags: php, magento, directory, cpanel, uploading

Not sure if i'm at the right place but oh well,

Since a month or two I've started working at a company which uses Magento. Everything was going smoothly, except for the fact that I now try to add an extension to the root directory of Magento through cPanel, in the installation guide I found the following steps:

**Installation:**

Before installing the extension, please make below notes complete:

- Clear your website cache under located at var/cache directory.
- If you’re installing extension on live website, please backup your store database and web directory.
- Disable Compilation by going to Admin Control Panel -> System -> Tool -> Compilation.

**Multi PRODUCT EDITOR Installation:**

- Extract Multi_Product_Editor-1.0.0.tgz file.
- Upload the extracted folders (/app, /js, /skin) respectively into the root of your Magento installation.
- From the Admin Control Panel, refresh cache at System => Cache Management. Log out and log in back

now I have found a problem with uploading the extracted folders, because

1. There are already a folder called App and one called Skin and I'm not sure if I should overwrite those
2. When I wanted to upload the specific folders, it can't, I can't upload the folder "App" and it only allows me clicking the folder and searching through the folder's folders.

I'm still new to Magento but I learn everyday! please tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if I need to take a step back, I gladly appreciate all your help!

Also, if I wasn't specific enough, or if you need more details, just say so and I'll try adding as much as I can :)

kind regards

Clay

Answer (score 0):

In magento app and skin are mandatory folders so you must not erase them. But if your module you want to add is adding properly, it will just add based on magento structure and create a new module in community or local for the app, and a new design in skin.

Be always careful of where the modules installs things anyway

Comment: Okay, so if i'm correct and understood you right, i should just try to add the app folder of the extension, and overwrite the ones which are already there, right?

Comment: If you have to overwrite something, it is usually bad news :)
You will have some folders existing ( for example app/code/community or app/code/local/), but if the thing you are installing is overwriting something in app/code/core, pay attention, this is really bad practice.
When you copy paste your files, ask for any merge manually and 95% of chances that your module won't overwrite a file. If it does, tell me which file is requested for overwrite.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! i'll do my best and try to add the files i want to and if i still experiencing problems i will get back to it! :)

Comment: Nope, still nothing, i can't upload a folder and it's only asking for a file, but there are many folders inside the extension folder called app, so a "file" is impossible, any ideas how i can upload the folder App from the extension i downloaded, and upload it in the Magento root directory?

Comment: for the app, it is quite easy, just extract the folder of your extension somewhere ( like in desktop). It should have in app/etc/modules one or two files to transfer, and in app/code/community or app/code/local on or few folders. Just copy paste them. They shouldnt exist in magento. If something is existing, tell me.

Comment: Okay, so if i understand you correctly, just extract the extension on desktop, and copy the contents of the folder (aka files) and paste them in the magento root directory in the folder like app?

Comment: yes, and if some files are asking for overwriting, say no, tell me which are concerned to copy them one by one later if needed